# Multiselect dropdown with checkbox in mvc4 razor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4 project where i have a multi select dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("year_selected", (SelectList)(ViewData["YearSelected"]), new { tabindex = "14", multiple = "multiple", style = "width:150px;height:200px;" })
```

Its populated with list of years i have mentioned in controller

```
int minYear =Int32.Parse(Helper.MinYear);
int maxYear = Int32.Parse(Helper.MaxYear);
var yearSelectedList = new List<SelectListItem>();
for (int count = minYear; count <= maxYear; count++)
{
    yearSelectedList.Add(new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = count.ToString(),
        Value = count.ToString()
        });
    }
    var yearselectlist = new SelectList(yearSelectedList, "Value", "Text");
    ViewData["YearSelected"] = yearselectlist;
```

and on dropdown click i am calling jquery to select that particular value and also when page is loaded i checking values saved in database by making them select by default

Here is jquery code to selected the values which are saved in database

```
if (str_year_selected.val() != "") {
    var yeararray = str_year_selected.val().split(",");
    for (var i in yeararray) {
         var val = yeararray[i];
         year_selected.find('option:[value=' + val + ']').attr('selected', 1);
    }
}
```

and here is code i am using to select the value when user clicks or press ctrl key on dropdown values

```
year_selected.change(function () {
     var selectedyears = "";
     $("#year_selected :selected").each(function (i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            selectedyears += ",";
        }
         selectedyears += $(this).text();
     });
     str_year_selected.val(selectedyears);
});
```

Everything is working perfect . but now problem is user wants checkbox inside of dropdown so that can check the option.

How do i do this ?

Comment: This link has checkboxes with in the dropdownlist,i hope this link is best suitable for your question.
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/#setselects-getselects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> user wants checkbox inside of dropdown so that can check the option.

There is a fantastic JQuery Plugin called `Dropdown Check List` that transforms a regular select HTML element into a dropdown checkbox list.

[image]

[Download](https://github.com/scottwb/jquery.ui.dropdownchecklist)

Answer (score 8):

Rather than using dropdown you can use checkbox in div with css. It will fell like it is a dropdown list with checkbox.

Here is good link of jquery

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial shows complete step by step guide for creating multiselect dropdown with checkboxes in mvc 
[Multiselect dropdown with checkboxes in MVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJNRlWpYArQ)

You Need Select Tag

```
<select id="CustomerId" name="CopyFromCustomerId"></select>
```

or you can use `Html.ListBoxFor`

You need following script

```
$('#CustomerId').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
```

And below css and script files

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
```